# Magento product with different options doesn't change price

Tags: magento

I've simple products in my magento store with custom options that have different prices. Upon selecting one of the given options e.g size, the total price doesn't change and stay the same. However if items purchased in shopping cart it shows correct price (base price+additional amount) I presume there's some javascript issue in my custom theme as when i changed the template to default it started to work normal. Any ideas what could be the possible issue and where should i be looking to sort this issue out.

Comment: is it possible to put a link of your website?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like a standard JavaScript error than something related directly to Magento. If I had to guess at random I'd say your theme is using jQuery (or another alternative), that is clashing with Prototype as it's not being ran in safe mode. To debug this, open up your site in a copy of FireFox with the web developer toolbar extension installed. In the top right hand corner of the page there are three circular icons. If the far right one is a red cross, there is a JavaScript error, clicking on the icon will tell you what the error is.

Comment: Thanks Cags, got it sorted there was a JS issue.